# AngularJS - Is there a way to overwrite a directive and prevent to original directive from executing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that registers a listener using the `$on()` function.

I am trying to overwrite this directive so that the registration of the listener is based on a condition. The problem is although the directive overwrite is working, the original directive is still running and the listener is still being registered even if the condition is not met.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: If you set the `priority` of the directive and afterwards remove the directive's attribute it won't go through the second one

Comment: @devqon Unfortunately, I don't think that is an option for me. The original directive also works with the 'Form' element. The directive that I am trying to overwrite is actually an overwrite of the ngForm directive. So I am trying to make a 3rd definition of it. For some reason I can't apply my changes on the second definition that's why I am making a 3rd one.